# How do I apply desktop media queries style to IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iphone, media-queries

I have two stylesheets, one should *only* apply to iPhone and other handhold devices

`@media screen and max-device-width: 480px { ... }`

and the other should *only* apply otherwise

`@media screen and min-device-width: 481px { ... }`

I currently put them in one large css file, in two different `@media` section mentioned above, but then **I realized IE7/8 doesn't apply any of the sections**.

What's the solution to the problem? The only solution I can [Googled](http://www.akademy.co.uk/blog/2010/03/css-style-ie6-media-hack/) is to include the desktop stylesheet again in an IE conditional comment:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/base.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<![endif]-->
```

But the [W3C](http://www.w3.org) website achieve the same effect without this. How?

Comment: Great, I just realized that W3C use `$("style").attr("media","screen");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment above, it seems the only two viable solution are conditional comment or Javascript `media` attribute rewrite.